# chef-- knife cookbook upload gives error ERROR: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory, on windows

Tags: chef-infra, knife, cookbook

I am new to Chef and learning it from Lynda, tutorial by Robin Beck. I am using Windows 10 and have installed ChefDk as per instructions in the tutorial. The tree structure is as below:

```
C:.
├───.chef
├───cookbooks
│   └───apache
│       ├───.delivery
│       │   └───build_cookbook
│       │       ├───data_bags
│       │       │   └───keys
│       │       ├───recipes
│       │       ├───secrets
│       │       └───test
│       │           └───fixtures
│       │               └───cookbooks
│       │                   └───test
│       │                       └───recipes
│       ├───recipes
│       ├───spec
│       │   └───unit
│       │       └───recipes
│       ├───templates
│       │   └───default
│       └───test
│           └───recipes
└───roles
```

I am trying to upload the cookbook using knife command:

`knife cookbook upload apache`

I am running the command from "chef-repo" directory but I am getting an error as below:
`ERROR: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory`

Please find below the screenshot for more information.

[image]

Please help, thanks in advance!

## EDIT:

Please find below the output of the knife.rb file.

```
#See http://docs.chef.io/config_rb_knife.html for more information on knife configuration options

current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)

log_level                :info

log_location             STDOUT

node_name                "hakiuser"

client_key               "#{current_dir}/hakiuser.pem"

chef_server_url          "https://api.chef.io/organizations/cheflynda"

cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]
```

Comment: Probably there is something missing inside the cookbook itself. Unfortunately your `tree` shows only directories and not files. May be `metadata.rb` is wrong or missing?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try uploading from the cookbook path?
In your case:

> cd C:\Users\Akshay\Downloads\Compressed\chef-repo\cookbooks
>   knife cookbook upload apache

if this doesn't work you can give the absolute path to the cookbook in the upload as well.

> knife upload -o PATH:PATH, --cookbook-path PATH:PATH

If above still doesn't work, could you print the output of your knife.rb? 
There should be your path to the chef-repo. Under

> knife[:chef_repo_path]

Comment: Base cookbook path [can be set in `knife.rb`](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_knife.html#settings), look for `cookbook_path`.

Comment: @nmanh Hi! thank you for your answer. The solutions you suggested did not work for me. I have added output of knife.rb file. Please suggest alternative solution.

Comment: I would try both of the following things:

- delete cookbook_path and do my first suggestion. Cd into the folder and start the upload from `C:\Users\Akshay\Downloads\Compressed\chef-repo\cookbooks`


---

OR

---


- where is your knife.rb located? Because `#{current_dir}/../cookbooks` depends on the current folder of your knife.rb. You could add the absolute path of your cookbooks. Like: `C:\Users\Akshay\Downloads\Compressed\chef-repo\cookbooks`

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking the same class and ran into the same problem. There must be something wrong with the Apache included with the class.
I downloaded a different one from:
https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/apache2
I was able to upload this one. Don't know how it's going to work though but at least I can proceed to the next lesson.